# Как правильно решить данную задачу на Python

Tags: python

Петя и Маша решили сыграть в игру. Изначально у Пети и Маши N и M яблок соответственно. Первым ходом Петя передает одно яблоко Маше. На второй ход Маша отдает Пете 2 яблока. Далее Петя передает Маше 3 яблока, и игра **продолжается до тех пор, пока у одного из игроков не заканчиваются яблоки**. Формально, на шаге i + 1 получатель яблок из шага i передает второму игроку число яблок, равное переданному числу яблок на шаге i и еще одно.

Напишите программу, которая по заданным N и M вычислит через сколько шагов игра Пети и Маши закончится.

В первой строке подается число N (1 ≤ N ≤ 106) — начальное число яблок у Пети. Во второй строке подается число M (1 ≤ N ≤ 106) — начальное число яблок у Маши.

Выведите одно число — количество ходов, через которое закончится игра.

Допустим, что наши входные данные это 2 и 3 то,

После первого хода: у Пети — 1 яблоко, у Маши — 4.

После второго: у Пети — 3 яблока, у Маши — 2.

После третьего: у Пети — 0 яблок, у Маши — 5.

Игра на этом заканчивается, так как у Пети больше не осталось яблок.

Я попытался это сделать таким образом, но по непонятной мне причине все ломается

```
a = int(input("Set a = "))
b = int(input("Set b = "))
i = 1
c = 0

while a > 0 or b > 0:
    a = a - i
    b = b + i
    i += 1
    c += 1
    a = a + i
    b = b - i
    i += 1
    c += 1
print(c)
```

a и b - это кол-во яблок у Маши и Пети
i - это кол-во которое они передают друг другу
c - это счетчик ходов

Comment: Во-первых, в `while` должно быть `and` вместо `or` (вы же хотите чтобы цикл продолжался пока оба числа не 0, а закончился когда хотя бы одно число обнулилось). Во-вторых, вы делаете 2 хода сразу но в середине не проверяете условие выхода.

Comment: Ну и незачем использовать 2 переменных `i` и `c` для, по-сути, одного и того же. Ведь в любой момент времени `i = c + 1` или `c = i - 1`. Так что будет достаточно какой-либо одной.

Comment: @GrAnd Хотя в данном случае, чтобы не запутаться в подсчётах, возможно две переменные и хорошо

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то решение проще некуда: `min(N*2-1, M*2)`. :)

Но если хотите типа *"реально поиграть"*, то:

```
N = int(input("Сколько яблок у Пети? "))
M = int(input("Сколько яблок у Маши? "))

i = 0
while N and M:
    i += 1
    if i % 2: N, M = N-i, M+i  # нечётный ход
    else:     N, M = N+i, M-i  # чётный ход

print(f"Игра закончится после {i} ходов.")
```

---

Ну или ваш код (исправленный):

```
a = int(input("Set a = "))
b = int(input("Set b = "))
i = 1
c = 0

while a > 0 and b > 0:           # здесь должен быть and
    a = a - i
    b = b + i
    i += 1
    c += 1
    if a == 0 or b == 0: break   # дополнительная проверка на условие конца игры перед каждым вторым ходом (обратной передаче яблок)
    a = a + i
    b = b - i
    i += 1
    c += 1
print(c)
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста объяснить как вы получили `min(N*2-1, M*2)`? Очень интересно:)

Comment: @JohnnySins Чисто умозаключительно... :) Если взглянуть на количество яблок, то можно уловить закономерность. Допустим, сначала `N=5`. Тогда "играя" получаем такую последовательность для `N`: **4** 6 **3** 7 **2** 8 **1** 9 **0**. Не трудно в ней заметить убывающую последовательность, которая доходит до нуля за `N*2-1` ходов. Для `M` - аналогично, только там на один ход больше, т.к. `M` "ходит вторым", т.е. `1+M*2-1`. Ну и дальше из этих двух чисел берётся минимальное , т.к. нам интересно то число, которое быстрее достигнет нуля.

Comment: Спасибо) Я просто на листочке экспериментально нашел эту закономерность, потом посмотрел ваш ответ и подумал что можно еще как-то по другому сделать